# Query MySQL... Select Multiple Results

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I am using

```
$query = "SELECT `username` FROM `database` WHERE `result` LIKE '%" . $arguments . "%'";
$connect = db_connect();
$query   = "SELECT `result` FROM `database` WHERE `username` = '" . $arguments . "';";
$get_users = db_query($query, $connect);
mysql_close($connect);

$data = $get_users[0]->result;
if ($get_users[0] == null) {
    die("No Results Found!");
} else {
    die($data);
}
```

The problem with this is that this query will look on my database for 1 user with the IP I provide because it looks on my database and the first result it finds it will stop the query and just echo that single username, I want it to return all the usernames attached to that IP.

Comment: May be your current filter has only one record.

Comment: are you passing multiple args like $arg1 , $arg2 ....multiple variables ...etc

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're asking. I'm no MySQL wizard, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't "spit". It would help if you [include more code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clarify what the expected output is, and what the output is that you're getting.

Comment: I have updated it, hopefully it is self explanatory now.

Answer (score 1):

Change your WHERE to:

```
WHERE result LIKE %val1% OR result LIKE %val2%
```

Another way suited for PHP:

```
$arguments= array('val1','val2');

//Escape arguments, trim, whatever before doing this
//Better use PDO or a similar, with prepared statements.
//query  
$qr = 'SELECT ... WHERE result IN ('.implode(',',$arguments).')';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can swap column result and variable $arguments:

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM database WHERE '".$arguments."' LIKE '%' + result + '%'";
```